# 80s or 90s cartoon series - Female protagonist has a large cat as a pet and collects crystals or gems

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, animals

I'm hoping to identify a cartoon that I remember watching on TV as a child. This would've been around 1998, so I would guess that the cartoon would be from either the 90s or possibly the 80s.

It was English language, and the art was stylistically closer to something like *Jem and the Holograms* or the *X-Men* cartoon.

I remember that the main character had dark or black hair and she had a large cat as a pet/companion (I'm 90% sure it was a white tiger). The story was that she had to fight the bad guys and collect some crystals or gems.
The show was more fantasy; I don't remember any hard sci-fi elements.
I also remember martial arts figuring into the story in some capacity, but I might be misremembering.

Answer (score 6):

Was it [*Tenko and the Guardians of the Magic*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenko_and_the_Guardians_of_the_Magic)? She had a pet white leopard I think, and was a magician but also had magic powers

[image: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcROb0_cxMgrt4jyk-0rGQ5GVxcuEkOHQ1uqxR0RwtFISsir6dm6WSExijazOEtOWwo2pLE&usqp=CAU]

[image]

you could buy a full grown version of her leopard as a toy:
[image]
https://www.jewelridersarchive.com/posts/tenko-and-the-guardians-of-the-magic/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This looks quite promising; are there any elements that match the question detail about collecting gems?

Comment: Yes, the plot revolves around Tenko and crew collecting the lost Starfire Gems

Answer (score 5):

Could this be the 1990/1991 show [Nadia: The Secret of Blue Water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadia:_The_Secret_of_Blue_Water)?

> Set in an alternate universe 1889, the series centers on Nadia, a 14-year-old girl of unknown origins, and Jean, a young, warm-hearted French inventor. Early in the story, the two protagonists are chased by Grandis Granva, Sanson, and Hanson, a group of jewel thieves who pursue Nadia for the blue jeweled pendant she possesses. After being rescued by Captain Nemo and his submarine, the Nautilus, the jewel thieves and the young protagonists join forces and participate in the struggle against the Neo-Atlantean forces, who seek to dominate the world.
>
> In the process, Nadia and Jean save the world from violent domination by the Neo-Atlantean forces led by Gargoyle, explore worldly mysteries and the powers of the blue pendant, uncover Nadia's hidden family ties, and ultimately discover the secret origins of Nadia.

[Nadia](https://nadia.fandom.com/wiki/Nadia) has a lion cub pet/friend named [King](https://nadia.fandom.com/wiki/King):
[image][image: lion cub named King]

Comment: That doesn't look familiar to me off-hand but I'll check it out, thank you. I remember the cat being a full-sized large cat, and I think the main character was paler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to [*Cybersix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersix_(TV_series)) (1999)

> The show is about a leather-clad female gynoid who works as a male teacher during the day, and fights against the scientist who created her at night
>
> [image]

I found your question trying to find the same answer and I ended up finding it and thought you'd like to scratch that 2 year long itch!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you [edit] in some details as to why you believe this is what the OP is looking for? Please see [answer] for some helpful tips